# Trying to code a Connection(Channel) Pool, for a Netty Client; What is the best approach?

Tags: netty

I need to develop a Netty Connection Pool which returns channels so I can avoid creating the channel every time its needed. The client is supposed to make several requests per second over Http, and is executed from a group of 10 threads.
Currently I've created a Netty Channel Pool, which works around this mechanism, but it doesn't seem to be connecting.

(Though it spawns out channels, the channels are unable to make successful 'write' on the network.

```
//Code follows
  //get Channel method
  public Channel getChannel() throws Exception 
  {
            synchronized (_channels) {
              PoolChannel pc = null;
              for (int i = 0; i < _channels.size(); i++) {
                pc = _channels.get(i);
                if (pc.lease()) {
                  // PoolConnection is available
                  if (!_checkChannels) {
                    return pc;
                  }
                  else {
                    // Check the status of the connection
                    boolean isHealthy = true;
                    try {
                      if (!pc.isOpen()) {
                    // If something wrong with the channel
                    // then don't use it anymore.
                        isHealthy = false;
                      }
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex) {
                      // If we can't even ask for that information, we
                      // certainly don't want to use it anymore.
                      isHealthy = false;
                    }

                    if (isHealthy) {
                      return pc;
                    }
                    else {
                      try {
                        pc.expire();
                      }
                      catch(Exception e) {
                        // ignore
                      }
                      _channels.remove(i);
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }

            // Create a new Connection
            PoolChannel pc=null;

            URI uri = _uri;
            String host = _host;
            int port = _port;

            //create channel
            Executor bossPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
            Executor workerPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

            ClientBootstrap bstrap = new ClientBootstrap(
                        new NioClientSocketChannelFactory(
                                bossPool, workerPool));
             bstrap.setPipelineFactory(new HttpClientPipelineFactory());

             ChannelFuture future = bstrap.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port));
             Channel chann = future.awaitUninterruptibly().getChannel();
             if (future.isSuccess()) {
                System.out.println("Channel success");
             }
            System.out.println("Channel = "+chann);
            pc = new PoolChannel(chann);
            pc.lease();

            // Add it to the pool
            synchronized (_channels) {
              _channels.add(pc);

              if (_cleaner == null) {
                // Put a new PoolCleaner
                _cleaner = new PoolCleaner(_cleaningInterval);
                _cleaner.start();
              }
            }

            return pc;
          }  

//===========================
```

Please can I get Help on this?
Also, as I am done with the Channel, how do I return this channel to the pool?
Is it sufficient just to close the channel?
Thanks in advance.